# Bulk entry in JSF data entry form

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am creating an application in jsf 1.2 with richfaces 3.3 (oracle 11g on BE). I need to incorporate a data entry form that will show names of like 800 individuals against which data would be entered in a grid or table like structure (like in excel sheet). This data entry table would be pagination based like 50 records would be displayed at a time with next and previous functionality. How this could be achieved in jsf.

Comment: This can be achieved using `<rich:dataTable>` and `<rich:datascroller>` tag components as shown in the live demo: [DataScroller demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTableScroller.jsf). You should also check the Scroller Facets Usage sample on the live demo link.

Comment: Dear Mendoza. my requirement is to add / edit data not just display the data.